# Indices of $(\text{Riem})^3$?

Tags: general-relativity, metric-tensor, curvature, perturbation-theory, effective-field-theory

This question relates to writing higher curvature terms in momentum space with respect to GR as an effective field theory.

I know that $R_{\alpha\beta\mu\nu} \sim \partial_\beta\partial_\mu h_{\alpha\nu}+\cdots$ wherethere is cycle of indices between $(\alpha\beta\mu\nu)$. But if I wanted to write higher curvature terms such Riemann squared, then I would assume the index structure would just be $~4R_{\mu\nu\alpha\beta}R^{\mu\nu\alpha\beta}$. But if I wanted to do this for a Riemann cubed term would I just write something along the lines of $R^3\sim R_{\mu\alpha}R^{\alpha\beta}R_\beta^\mu$ and then expand this in terms of the definition of the Ricci tensor? Or am I being sloppy with what indices I am contracting that would lead to nonsense?

(I am also interested in $R^4\sim R_{\mu\alpha}R^{\alpha\gamma}R_{\gamma\beta}R^{\beta\mu}$ but again, I believe I may be playing it fast and loose with indices and how they should be written and/or constrained).

Answer (score 2):

You should be careful when you say $R^3\sim R_{\mu\alpha}R^{\alpha\beta}R_\beta^\mu$. This is a bit misleading.

$R$ is the Ricci scalar. $R_{\mu \nu}$ is the Ricci tensor. And $R_{\mu \nu \rho \sigma}$ is the Riemann tensor. Your statement like above is not correct for the same reason that $R \sim R_{\mu \nu} R^{\mu \nu}$ is not correct. The expressions on the left and right are completely different. It is only when you contract indices with the metric tensor $g_{\mu \nu}$ that you can go from higher-rank curvature tensors to lower-rank ones. Otherwise, contracting indices between just curvature tensors leads to different objects.

So it's better to write something like $(Ricci)^3\sim R_{\mu\alpha}R^{\alpha\beta}R_\beta^\mu$, which is what you will sometimes see in literature. But a much better, complete, and correct way is to write curvature tensors with all their indices explicitly (instead of just saying 'Ricci'). This is because you can have many distinct possible contractions between curvature tensors. For instance $R_{\mu \nu \rho \sigma} R^{\mu \nu \rho \sigma}$ and $R_{\mu \rho \nu \sigma} R^{\mu \nu \rho \sigma}$: they are both different objects.

If your aim is to write down an effective field theory, then you should consider all possible contractions at a certain level. Given a list of curvature tensors, there is some hard work involved in trying to write down all possible contractions of indices between them. This is best done using tensor computer algebra software these days. I recommend [xAct/xTras](http://www.xact.es/xtras/documentation/ref/AllContractions.html).